# Why is cd without arguments not working

Tags: command-line, bash, home-directory, cd

I'm used to typing

```
$ cd
```

without arguments to navigate to my home directory in the bash shell.

However, since some undetermined time, this does not work anymore and simply does nothing.

My `HOME` variable is set:

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/me
```

How can this be? The manpage says

```
If no directory operand is given and the HOME environment variable is set to a non-empty
value, the cd utility shall behave as if the directory named in the HOME environment
variable was specified as the directory operand.
```

Some relevant stuff:

```
$ uname -a
Linux eris 4.15.0-96-generic #97-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 1 03:25:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ bash --version 
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: What does `type -a cd` say? what is the result of `cd && pwd`?

Comment: Oups, guess you solved it! Totally forgot that I did this:
`cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    mkdir "$1" &> /dev/null;
    builtin cd "$1"
}
cd is a shell builtin`

Answer (score 1):

I guess something wrong in your .alias or .bashrc file.
You can try to remove all the alias, connected to cd. See if something is wrong, using:

```
cat $HOME/.alias | grep 'cd '
```

or

```
cat $HOME/.bashrc | grep 'cd '
```

If something is wrong indeed, then open it with nano and remove / fix this wrong line.

```
nano $HOME/.alias
source  $HOME/.alias
```

or

```
nano $HOME/.bashrc
source  $HOME/.bashrc
```